# How can I access the request object in an aspectj class in web application

Tags: java, web, liferay, aspectj

I'm working on a Liferay 7.0 plugin project (traditional WAR packaging). I'm using AOP in it and have made my required AspectJ classes. I want to get the `request` object in the aspect class and get some attributes from it.
For this task, I implemented a `ServletRequestListener` that set the `request` object in a `ThreadLocal` variable; but because of the setter thread may be different from the getter thread, the `ThreadLocal` variable's value may be null sometimes, when I get it in the aspect class.
What solution do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add in the code snippet that you are using?

Comment: Could you test if `ServiceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext().getRequest()` returns the desired object already? May be it is set here already?